# Identifying the collections of topologies on a set whose union is a topology on that set

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

A follow up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3208639/defining-the-class-of-sets-for-which-the-union-of-topologies-is-a-topology-sets). Let $\mathbf{set}$ be the class of sets. For every set $X$, let $\mathbf{top}(X)$ be the collection of topologies on $X$.

(The following is a verification of everything in the answer to the previous question, feel free to skip ahead.)

---

---

**'Theorem' $1$**

The set [class?] of sets for which the union of two topologies is always a topology is the set [class?] of sets with a cardinality of, at most, $2$.

*Proof*

Let $T(n)$ be the number of topologies on a set of cardinality $n$ (see [A000798](https://oeis.org/A000798))

From $T(0)=1$, it follows that $|X|=0\implies |\mathbf{top}(X)|=1$, whence $\{\bigcup\mathbf{top}(X)\}=\mathbf{top}(X)$;

From $T(1)=1$, it follows that $|X|=1\implies |\mathbf{top}(X)|=1$, whence $\{\bigcup\mathbf{top}(X)\}=\mathbf{top}(X)$;

WLOG, let $X=\{x,y\}$, then...

$$\mathbf{top}(X)=\{\{\emptyset,\{x,y\}\},\{\emptyset,\{x\},\{x,y\}\},\{\emptyset,\{y\},\{x,y\}\},\{\emptyset,\{x\},\{y\},\{x,y\}\}\}$$

By exaustion...

$$\forall T\subseteq\mathbf{top}(X).\bigcup_{\tau\in T}\tau\in\mathbf{top}(X)$$

Thus,...

$$|X|\leq2\implies \forall T\subseteq\mathbf{top}(X).\bigcup_{\tau\in T}\tau\in\mathbf{top}(X)$$

WLOG, let...

$$X=\{x,y\}\cup Z\quad:\quad Z\neq\emptyset$$

...then...

$$\tau_1=\{\emptyset,\{x\},X\}\land\tau_2=\{\emptyset,\{y\},X\}\implies\tau_1,\tau_2\in\mathbf{top}(X)$$

$$\{x\},\{y\}\in\tau_1\cup\tau_2\land\{x\}\cup\{y\}\notin\tau_1\cup\tau_2\implies\tau_1\cup\tau_2\notin\mathbf{top}(X)$$

Thus,...

$$|X|>2\implies \exists T\subseteq\mathbf{top}(X).\bigcup_{\tau\in T}\tau\notin\mathbf{top}(X)$$

Therefore...

$$\forall X\in\mathbf{set}.\left(\forall T\subseteq\mathbf{top}(X).\bigcup_{\tau\in T}\tau\in\mathbf{top}(X)\iff|X|\leq 2\right)\quad\square$$

**'Theorem' 2**

The class of sets for which the union of topologies is not necessarily a topology is the class of sets with cardinality greater than $2$.

*Proof*

Follows directly from thm. 1. $\quad\square$

**'Theorem' 3.**

For every set $X$, there exists a collection of topologies $T\subseteq\mathbf{top}(X)$ such that $\forall S\subseteq T.\bigcup_{\tau\in S}\tau\in\mathbf{top}(X)$

*Proof*

$$\forall X\in\mathbf{set}.\{\emptyset, X\},\mathcal{P}(X)\in\mathbf{top}(X)\iff\{\{\emptyset, X\},\mathcal{P}(X)\}\subseteq\mathbf{top}(X)$$

$$\bigcup \{\{\emptyset, X\},\mathcal{P}(X)\}=\mathcal{P}(X)\in\mathbf{top}(X)\quad\square$$

---

---

**Question:**

Given that, for every set $X$, there is a collection $T$ of subsets of $\mathbf{top}(X)$ such that the union of any [possibly finite] number of elements of each member of $T$ is a topology (on $X$), how can I characterize $T$?

I had considered as a trivial case...

$$T_x=\{\tau\in\mathbf{top}(X)\mid\{x\}\in \tau\}$$

$$T=\bigcup_{x\in X}\{T_x\}$$

e.g.

$T_x=\{\{\emptyset,\{x\},X\},\quad\{\emptyset,\{x\},\{x,y\},X\},\quad\{\emptyset,\{x\},\{x,y\},\{x,y,z\},X\},\quad\ldots,\quad\{\emptyset,\{x\},\{y\},\{x,y\},X\},\quad\{\emptyset,\{x\},\{y\},\{x,y\},\{x,y,z\},X\},\quad\ldots\}$

$T_y=\{\{\emptyset,\{y\},X\},\quad\{\emptyset,\{y\},\{x,y\},X\},\ \ldots\ldots\ldots\}$
and so on, but I doubt that this is the only case.

**Edit:**

The desired collection of topologies can be written as...

$$T=\left\{S\subseteq\mathbf{top}(X)\ \bigg\vert\ \bigcup S\in\mathbf{top}(X)\right\}$$

Since $T$ is closed under intersection, $T\cup\emptyset$ is trivially a topology on some subset of $\mathbf{top}(X)$. As a topology on a subset of $\mathbf{top}(X)$, $T$ is also a subset of a topology on $\mathbf{top}(X)$. It may be the case that the topology on $\mathbf{top}(X)$ containing $T$ as a subset is unique, which may make it easier to identify.

Comment: You are messing up your elements and inclusions. For example, at the bottom, $S$ should not be a *subset* of $\mathbf{top}(X)$ (that would make $S$ a collection of topologies, and then $\{x\}\in S$ would always be false), $S$ should be an **element** of $\mathbf{top}(X)$ (that is, your $S$ is a topology on $X$, not a collection of topologies on $X$). You have similar problems throughout: $T$ is not "a collection of sets of subset of $\mathrm{top}(X)$", $T$ is a collection of **elements** of $\mathrm{top}(X)$. You need to clarify that whole bunch of things first.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I thought that too, but then I realised that there is more than one collection of topologies whose union is a topology, but the union of two such collections of topologies may contain topologies whose union is not a topology. For example, the union of $A_x$ and $A_y$ contains $\{\emptyset,\{x\},X\}$ and $\{\emptyset,\{y\},X\}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I did make a few mistakes though, so thanks for pointing that out!